# finding ip range via subnet mask

Tags: python, networking, subnet

Let's say my local ip is `10.212.97.23` and my Subnet Mask is `255.255.254.0`

According to that, I'm in the same subnet with `10.212.96.*` and CIDR would be `10.212.96.0/23`

So my question is: Is there any python library which takes local ip and subnet mask and calculates the CIDR value? I checked netaddr library but couldn't find this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic count in CIDR can be computed manually using the below function without using any libraries:

```
>>> netmask = "255.255.254.0"
>>> sum([bin(int(x)).count("1") for x in netmask.split(".")])
23
```

Let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, for example if I add "/23" string to my local ip it will be "10.212.97.23/23", is it refers to same ip range with "10.212.96.0/23" ?

Comment: They should be in same ip range.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with a module, the ipaddress module can help:

```
❯ python3
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.IPv4Network("10.212.97.23/255.255.254.0", strict=False).prefixlen
23
```

Docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html).